# 'data.forEach is not a function' when loading csv in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building a simple feedback system for a study. I have just started to learn JS and D3.js, but decided to build some very simple plot in D3.js. However, I get the following error message and I don't understand how I can fix it?

**(index):36 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function**

What I want to do with this script is to take a single line in a .csv and put the number  on the screen. This my code

```
const inter = setInterval(function() {
                updateData();
        }, 5000); 

// ** PLOG
function updateData() {

    // Get the data again
    d3.csv("lagplot.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.finish = +d.FINISH;
            d.bib = +d.BIB;
        });
        

    // PLOT TEXT
        d3.select("text")   
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
                .attr("fill", "teal")
                .text(function(d) { return d.finish; })
            });
        }
```

And this how the csv file looks

```
    Unnamed: 0  RANK  STA  RUN  BIB           NAME  INTER 1  INTER 1.1  INTER 1.2    INTER 2   INTER 2.1  INTER 2.2  FINISH     FINISH.1  FINISH.2   COURSE
33          33    34    9    4    2  OFTEBRO Einar     4.85       3.72         33  10.145.29  +8.10+4.38     3232.0  14.053  +11.28+3.18      32.0  LØYPE 3
```

Comment: Have you checked the network tab of your devtools to see if the file is actually loaded? Are there any errors displayed in the console? Does the `error` parameter contain anything? Because `data` seems to either be `null` or something other than an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#csv), the function you're passing to `d3.csv()` is not a callback, but a *row conversion function* - what you're passed is not `(error, data)` but just `d` (the row being converted). You should skip the `data.forEach` and use the row conversion function for that, and put the rest of the code in the `.then()` callback.

```
// Get the data again
d3.csv("lagplot.csv", function(d) {
    d.finish = +d.FINISH;
    d.bib = +d.BIB;
    return d;
}).then(function(data) {
    // PLOT TEXT
    d3.select("text")   
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "teal")
        .text(function(d) { return d.finish; })
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the inspiration from this https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6bd13f974d6516f3e491. I just wonder how I can implement the automatic refresher now?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. What causes the error is the difference in `d3` versions. Most of the tutorials on the web were written for `v3` or `v4` where you loaded the csvs in the way you've written. If you try to do this with `v5` or later, you'll get the error. Check your `<script>` tag for `d3` and either change it to `v4` or change your code along the lines that Klaycon suggested in his answer.